# Find a triplet that sum to a given value gives TLE in Java

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, hashmap, sum

I am trying to solve this question https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/triplet-sum-in-array-1587115621/1#
I have used a HashMap to store all the possible sums along with an array of indices whose sum I have stored. This is my code

```
  class Solution
 {

//Function to find if there exists a triplet in the array A[] which sums up to X. 
  
 public static boolean find3Numbers(int arr[], int n, int X){ `
  
 HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Pair>> hm=new HashMap<>();

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
            if(!hm.containsKey(arr[i]+arr[j])){hm.put(arr[i]+arr[j],new ArrayList<>());}
            Pair pair=new Pair(i,j);
            ArrayList<Pair> list=hm.get(arr[i]+arr[j]);
            list.add(pair);
            hm.put(arr[i]+arr[j],list);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(hm.containsKey(X-arr[i])){
            ArrayList<Pair> p=hm.get(X-arr[i]);
            for(int k=0;k<p.size();k++){
                if(p.get(k).ind1!=i && p.get(k).ind2!=i)return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public static class Pair{
    int ind1;
    int ind2;
    Pair(int i,int j){
        ind1=i;
        ind2=j;
    }
}
}
```

Please tell me why am I getting TLE?

Comment: What is TLE? Also, can you describe the task here instead of linking to it? Links can break, making the question useless for others. See also [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description of the problem, time complexity should be O(n^2). But this part of your code is not O(n^2), in worst case it is O(n^3)

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(hm.containsKey(X-arr[i])){
        ArrayList<Pair> p=hm.get(X-arr[i]);
        for(int k=0;k<p.size();k++){
            if(p.get(k).ind1!=i && p.get(k).ind2!=i)return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Because ArrayList's size can be n^2. For example, [1,1,1,1,1]. List of pairs which sum is 2 is 10.

```
(n - 1) + (n - 2) + (n - 3) + ... + 2 + 1 = (n - 1) * n / 2 ≈ n^2
```

The possible solution:

```
public static boolean find3Numbers(int arr[], int n, int X){
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) { // from the second to penultimate
        int l = 0; // first index
        int r = n - 1; // last index
        while (l < i && r > i) {
            int sum = arr[l] + arr[r] + arr[i];
            if (sum == X)
                return true;
            if (X > sum)
                l++;
            else
                r--;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

- time complexity - O(n^2)
- space complexity - O(1)

This approach is also called "Two Pointer technique", it is widely used in algorithmic problems. If you are interested, you can find a lot of information on the internet.

Comment: Describing the problem is half the solution, not fit for an answer. You are more likely to get upvotes if you also provide the O(n^2) solution.

Comment: Ok, I added solution to my answer

Comment: Great. Please also describe the solution for beginners. While writing an answer on SO, be as thorough as possible.

Comment: Is there no way to solve this problem in O(n^2) without sorting the array? I am just curious.

Answer (score 0):

```
 package com.test;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.List;

    public class TripletSum {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, -3, 4, 9, -2, -1 };
        System.out.println(TripletSum.getTriplet(arr, 1));
}

    private static List<List<Integer>> getTriplet(int[] arr, int target) {
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        List<List<Integer>> allTriplets = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
         for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 2; i++) {
            int sum = target - arr[i];
            int start = i + 1;
            int end = arr.length - 1;
            while (start < end) {
            int t = arr[start] + arr[end];
            if (t == sum) {
                allTriplets.add(Arrays.asList(arr[start], arr[end], arr[i]));
                start++;
                end--;
            } else if (t < sum) {
                start++;
            } else {
                end--;
            }
        }

    }

         return allTriplets;

}
```

}